# Create encrypted (password protected) zip file

Tags: encryption, zip

How do I create an encrypted (password protected) zip file?

Comment: Related: [Compressing folders with password via command line](http://askubuntu.com/q/342900/367990)

Comment: Note, that Zip Passwords is no protection! those can be easily broken! use 7-Zip with a long password instead, or better GNUPG encryption!

Comment: Modern ZIP files support at least two encryption methods and the AES-256 encryption is safe when you use long enough passphrase. However, as ZIP files do not support modern password hashing, use of short passwords with even AES-256 encrypted ZIP is even more dangerous than short passwords in general. Also note that some older software that support ZIP files may not support AES-256 encrypted ZIP files so if compatibility with older software is important, all ZIP encrypted files should be weak.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

This will prompt for a password:

```
zip --encrypt file.zip files
```

---

This is more insecure, as the password is entered/shown as plain text:

```
zip --password (password) file.zip files
```

---

Warning, the standard zip encryption is very weak and is easily cracked.
Note, Use `-r` to zip directory and subdirectory recursively.

Comment: Is there a better option from the standard encryption?

Comment: Using gnupg on the final zip with a key for yourself or your destination.

Comment: Does not work `file.zip` is empty

Comment: @Black If you're trying to compress a folder, then you need to use `-r` switch. So it'll be `zip --encrypt file.zip -r your_folder`

Comment: is it compatible with windows, if recipient is wondows user ?

Comment: @BudiMulyo Yes. It's compatible with Windows.

Comment: It requires password when I call unzip in Linux Mint, but you can open the archive and see files list without opening them.

Comment: I use this command as mentioned above  -  zip -r --password 'Password123' test.zip test/

Answer (score 53):

Starting from Ubuntu 17.10, right-clicking and selecting "Compress" no longer has "Other Options" listed.

To resolve this, open "Archive Manager"  and then drag & drop the files/folders from your File Manager into it and it will appear.

Comment: If Archive Manager is not installed (as in my lightweight debian for example), it can be installed with `$ su root -c 'apt-get install file-roller'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only option right now. But it’s not *that* many clicks more. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/868493/how-to-make-files-use-file-roller-again

Comment: It appears that this functionality is restored in (at least) 22.04, but the UI is a little different now.  Click the extension drop-down (.zip) and choose ".zip  (Password protected zip, must be installed on Windows and Mac.)" instead.

Answer (score 31):

You can also right-click on a folder or file(s) in Nautilus and select "Compress...".  In the resulting window, you can expand the "Other Options" section to enter a password.

[image]

If the password field or any of the other options are not enabled, then the selected compression option does not support it.  Select a different one from the list after the filename.  According to the documentation:

> Currently, only 7-Zip, ZIP, RAR and ARJ archives support encryption

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to install `.rar` before you can use it in the compressor.

Comment: I don't see "Other Options" anymore in Ubuntu 17.10 (I remember seeing it in earlier version though)

Comment: @Jonathan No solution, but related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/868493/how-to-make-files-use-file-roller-again

Answer (score 31):

Comments and answers have mentioned the default zip encryption is weak, but since there is no code example, here is on with .7zip:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full  # install 7zip
7za a -tzip -p -mem=AES256 foo_file.zip foo_folder  # encrypt folder
```

Commands explained:

- `7za`: Use 7zip
- `a`: Append? / Adding files?  (`e` for extraction)
- `-tzip`: Use .zip format instead of default .7z
- `-p`: specify a password for encryption
- `-mem=AES256`: Use AES256 encryption
- `foo_file.zip`: Name of .zip file
- `foo_folder`: Name of folder to encrypt

Answer based on: https://www.tecmint.com/7zip-command-examples-in-linux/

Comment: can this be extracted by any unzipping software ?

Comment: I think the resulting .zip is the same as using software on Windows to create a .zip with a password. I haven't experienced anyone telling me they couldn't unzip this, but I haven't used it often.

Comment: Windows zip folder does not support AES256. 7-zip or WinZip (maybe WinRAR too?) should be able to extract it.

Comment: Best answer since it has good encryption. Double-clicking a file zipped in this manner in the [`nemo` file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu/1173861#1173861) at least (but probably on Ubuntu's default `nautilus` file manager too) on Ubuntu allows you to open and decrypt via a GUI, making it very easy and intuitive for a recipient to decrypt on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI I tried extracting this on a fresh install of Win11 using its built-in capability (Windows Explorer) and it failed with an error.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install zip
zip -r --encrypt result.zip folder
```

1. Install zip
2. Use `-r` to zip directory and subdirectory
3. Use `--encrypt` to secure your files

   > with a simple password-based symmetric encryption system, which is documented in the ZIP specification

   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Encryption)

Comment: Thumb up for "-r" flag.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt

```
gpg -c your.zip
```

creates `your.zip.gpg`

Decrypt:

```
gpg your.zip.gpg
```

[To turn off password caching](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103037/43781)

More details including directories.

https://superuser.com/a/249516/27275

Answer (score 1):

## with [bsdtar](https://www.mankier.com/1/bsdtar)

Encrypt `a_file`, creating the encrypted archive `encrypted.zip` (you'll be prompted for a password):

```
bsdtar --options zip:encryption -acf encrypted.zip a_file
```

Decrypt and extract the file from the encrypted archive:

```
bsdtar -xf encrypted.zip
```

---

The `-a` option when creating the archive makes bsdtar choose the archive format and its compression using the ending of the archive, `.zip`. If you don't add `-a`, you'll get this error message:

> bsdtar: Unknown module name: `zip'

Answer (score 0):

The metadata (filenames) of an encrypted zip can be read with `unzip -l`

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/186878/can-the-content-of-a-password-protected-zip-file-be-known

The solution, as described in that link is to double-zip it but it is really not elegant.

Also, some email providers block that kind of attachment, [gmail for example](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way of compressing by encrypting and extracting by decrypting.

You can use the following to compress `zip -er output.zip <folder_to_compress>`.

It will prompt you for a password. Enter password.

To decrypt/extract use `unzip <output.zip>`.