# Compressing folders with password via command line

Tags: command-line, compression, zip

I would like to know whether it is possible to do the following via CLI.

I have a Folder `F` which contains several sub folders and some files. I want to compress folder `F` into `.zip` file with the "password-only-extract".

Comment: Related: [Create encrypted (password protected) zip file](http://askubuntu.com/q/17641/367990)

Comment: googlers... →please stop putting _any_ trust in zip password „protection“ – see [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/342902/479118)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Go to the relevant folder using the `cd` command like this:

```
cd /path/to/folder/
```

(If your folder `F` is in your Home folder, you can just do `cd ~`.)

Then, type in your terminal:

```
zip -er F.zip F
```

This will prompt you for a password. Give it, and that will create a password-protected zip file from that folder.

- **`-e`** enables encryption for your zip file. This is what makes it ask for the password.
- **`-r`** makes the command recursive, meaning that all the files inside the folder will be added to the zip file.
- **`F.zip`** is the name of the output file.
- **`F`** is the folder you want to zip.

There is an option called **`-P`** that will allow you to pass the password in the command itself, but that is not good because there is always the **threat of over-the-shoulder peeking**. Also other users can see the password by using `ps -ef` command if you use `-P` switch. With that `-P` switch, the command will look like this:

```
zip -P password -r F.zip F
```

- Visit [`man zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/zip) for more information.

Comment: -e means encrypt

Comment: Hey I just edited your question to include a little bit of context. But can you edit it to include your `-e means encrypt` comment, as well as the meaning of the `-r` option. Thanks!

Comment: Tx Dedunu for your input.Just one more clarification needed.What if I need to automate this ...What I mean is if instead of prompting for a password can I set a password in the command itself ?

Comment: I added that also.

Comment: But it is higly unrecommended to use because your history will be recorded. otherwise other users can see your password with "ps aux"

Comment: Thanks again Alaa! I'm not good at organizing and formatting. :(

Comment: Attention: Zip passwords can be easily broken. use 7-Zip with a long password instead (see answer below), or better GNUPG encryption!

Answer (score 56):

The encryption of zip files is weak and can be broken very easily. Instead use 7zip.

```
7z a -p Fdirectory.7z /path/to/F
```

- `a` command tells 7zip to add files.
- `-p` You can either, leave it blank so it asks you interactively or type your password here.
- `Fdirectory.7z` is the name of the to-be-created archive.
- `/path/to/F` is the path of your directory. It can be relative or full path.

Is recommendable not typing the password in the shell since it's visible to anyone with access to the `/proc` directory.

Then to decrypt and extract the files later:

```
7z x ../Fdirectory.7z
```

Comment: It seems if you pass `-p` only to `7z` and omit the password, it asks for it interactively - even a second time for confirmation.

Comment: @ssc that is the most useful option, yet it isn't in the manual pages..

Comment: I tried the above command to compress a folder with few files totaling ~19kB in size. Yet It takes about 2 minutes! Why it takes so long?

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 Don't use the -r flag to recurse. 7z _will_ recurse the source directory without that flag. `-r` will instead add all files and subdirectories of the _current working directory_. The man page for 7z specifically warns against this and says that this flag should be avoided. https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z

Comment: @HåkenLid Nice catch! I did used the -r flag even if I did not mention it above. That was it! Thank you!

Comment: You should use at least a very long password, that is brute-force-safe. But It seems like [7-Zip has also been cracked](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51900/forgot-password-to-7-zip-archive) by now, so if it has to be secure, use GNUPG to encrypt your files

Comment: @rubo77 any format is liable to bruteforcing, but 7zip algo isn't easily breakable as shown by the very answer where >12 characters password might be impossible.

Comment: @rubo77 The link you shown doesn't crack 7zip. It is just bruteforce guessing the password.