# How to make Files use file-roller again?

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, archive, compression, file-roller

How can I get more options (in addition to zip, tar.xz and 7z) and the option to add password when making archive files in file-roller in Gnome 3.22? Thanks!

Screen-shot of new create archive in Files (nautilus) 3.26.0
[image]

Archive Manager (file-roller)
[image]

Comment: What options do you want?

Comment: Well, as you can see in the screen-shot I've attached, new file roller offers you only three simple options zip, tar.xz and 7z. We used to see all  the other file formats listed there in earlier versions plus the option to password protect an archive file. I understand that you can get all these in Archive Manager. But I would like to enjoy the ease of making a password-protected archive file simply by right-clicking on a folder/file in nautilus.

Comment: I too want more options in File Roller. However, I want to set the compression option like "-9" for maximum compression. I don't see this either version. I thought gnome 3.22 Nautilus has compression built in, and does not need File Roller.

Comment: Package `nautilus-actions` is gone in 18.04 Bionic Beaver. A workaround is to install `nemo` (my favorite file browser) and from `nemo` you will find the context menu working just as before!

Comment: Waaaay! Suggested answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/969650/how-to-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-17-10-like-in-17-04/969651)  still works, although I'm not totally in love with sub-menu, you can download `libunique` from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libunique-3.0-0/download and install it with `gdebi`, followed by `nautilus-actions` from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/nautilus-actions/3.2.3-1build5 and do it with `gdebi` as well!

Comment: As of `3.26` there is no encryption option for any type. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## Set a password to encrypt data in a new archive by following these steps:

Start creating a new archive.

At the bottom of the file chooser dialog you can choose a File Format and enter a password into the Password field in Other Options.

Choose an archive type that can be password protected before setting a password.

Continue with creating a new archive.

## Protect an existing archive by setting a password:

Open an archive.

Click Edit ▸ Password….

Type a password into the Password field.

If you want to encrypt the list of files tick Encrypt the file list too.

Click OK to continue.

Archive Manager will encrypt only new files which will be added to the archive!

**The following archive formats are well supported, and installed by default in File Roller:**

*Tar gzip bzip bzip2 LZMA ZIP JAR CD images*

**The following formats require additional packages to be used. They may have incomplete support, with some requiring non-free software to have full support.**

*7zip shar ARJ ACE RAR LRZ LHA lZO*

[Source](https://help.gnome.org/users/file-roller/stable/index.html.en)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I can achieve this through the Archive Manager. But we used to be able to compress a folder/file and add a password simply by right-clicking in earlier versions of file-roller. Just wondered if there is any way to get these options back in Gnome 3.22