# How to make nautilus use file-roller in 17.10 like in 17.04?

Tags: nautilus, archive, compression, file-roller

In Ubuntu 17.10 ubuntu upgraded Nautilus (File Browser) to version 3.26.0. New nautilus is not using file-roller anymore, it has [switched](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/archive/2016/projects/5271934111580160/) to an integrated compression mechanism.

[image: New mechanism]

This makes it complicated to create encrypted archives and/or different types compression archives that file-roller does provide.

How to make nautilus use file-roller as before?

Related question: [How to get more options in File-Roller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868493/how-to-get-more-options-in-file-roller)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install nautilus-actions:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-actions
```

- Context Label: `Compress with FR`
- Create new action; path: `file-roller`
- Parameters: `-d %F`
- Working diretory: `%d`

For installing `nautilus-actions` in 18.04, see [Nautilus-actions in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030940/nautilus-actions-in-18-04).

Comment: Package is gone in 18.04 Bionic Beaver. A workaround is to install `nemo` (my favorite file browser) and from `nemo` you will find the context menu working just as before!

Comment: Waaaay! Your answer still works, although I'm not totally in love with sub-menu, you can download `libunique` from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libunique-3.0-0/download and install it with `gdebi`, followed by `nautilus-actions` from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/nautilus-actions/3.2.3-1build5 and do it with `gdebi` as well!