# How can I reinstate file roller/ archive manager to work with Nautilus, in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, file-roller

In Ubuntu 16.04 I could compress a file or folder by right clicking on it and the File Roller/Archive Manager window would pop up allowing me to set a password or split the archive into volumes.

In Ubuntu 18.04 this functionality is gone and is substituted by a Nautilus window not giving you any options other than the name or the archive type.

How can I reinstate file roller/ archive manager  to work with Nautilus, in Ubuntu 18.04?

It is the same problem as [How to make nautilus use file-roller in 17.10 like in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969650/how-to-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-17-10-like-in-17-04) but the difference is that the package `nautilus-actions` is not available in Ubuntu 18.04, so I cannot proceed with the answer to that question.

Comment: It seems that it is time to switch from [degrading Nautilus](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/28) to Caja or Nemo, or globally from degrading GNOME to the power of MATE or Cinnamon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make nautilus use file-roller in 17.10 like in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969650/how-to-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-17-10-like-in-17-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nautilus-actions in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030940/nautilus-actions-in-18-04)