# How do I make nautilus use file-roller in Ubuntu 18.04 and above like in 17.04?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, archive, compression, file-roller

New nautilus is not using file-roller any more by default, it has switched to its native expression, but I want to use file-roller on right click.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/969651/550618), which worked in Ubuntu 17.10. But `nautilus-actions` package is not yet Ubuntu 18.04's official repositories.

So is there any other method for this purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ubuntu 18.04+ method:**

Since `nautilus-actions` package is not yet in Ubuntu 18.04's official repositories, it's better to use nautilus script instead of nautilus-actions, which doesn't require any additional installation like for nautilus-actions.

You can do it easily by below commands:

```
echo file-roller -d \$@ > ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/File-Roller
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/File-Roller
```

After that you can see File-Roller option in right click Scripts menu.

[image: File-Roller]

Comment: FYI `filemanager-actions` is packaged in `ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions` PPA (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509)). So you can extend your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [NOrbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) said, filemanager-actions is packaged in ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions PPA .

You can install them as usual:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension # Nautilus
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-caja-extension # Caja
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nemo-extension # Nemo
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions* # simply all filemanagers

echo file-roller -d \$@ > ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/File-Roller
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/File-Roller
```

Comment: **Important note: For Ubuntu 18.04 only!**