# How compress rar with context menu nautilus

Tags: nautilus, compression, zip, context-menu, rar

In Ubuntu 16.04 i right click folder and select compress type and split size
but in 18.04 compress menu not like before and choose type menu in gone
[image]

i install unrar zip unzip p7zip-full p7zip-rar rar file-roller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the nautilus extension for fileroller, which now provides the right-click option and the dialog, indeed does not anymore support the creation of alternative archive formats, even if the supporting application is installed. You will need to resort to an alternative approach.

**1. Use fileroller directly**

Fileroller itself still maintains the rar support. Thus, you can open fileroller (search for "Archive Manager" or "fileroller") and create the rar archive from there.

**2. Create your custom right-click menu item for rar**

If you prefer having a right-click menu item, then you can explore one of several options to add custom right-click menus to Files (nautilus).

*2.a Nautilus scripts*: You can create [nautilus scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) which can be started from the right-click menu. These scripts live in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`. Scripts that are set 'executable' will appear in a new "Scripts" submenu of your right-click menu. How this is easily done is indicated in [How do I make nautilus use file-roller in Ubuntu 18.04 and above like in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072014/how-do-i-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-above-like-in-17-04/1072015#1072015) (Thanks to TiTAN for the hint!)

*2.b Filemanager-actions or nautilus-python*: Other possibilities are outlined in this [Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus/77285#77285). Look for "Update for Ubuntu 18.04" for the application `filemanager-actions`, and the answer of mnrl for relying on python-nautilus.

Comment: i use this [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072015/859739)

Comment: @TiTAN thanks for pointing to the script. This indeed is a dead-simple and very effective approach. Added the link to the answer.