# Unable to lock Zip file Ubuntu 18

Tags: command-line, 18.04, compression, zip

I am trying to make a locked ZIP folder in Ubuntu 18.04. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17641/create-encrypted-password-protected-zip-file) post, but it locked the files inside it and not the ZIP folder as a whole. I can open the ZIP folder without providing a password and when I attempt to open the files inside it, it prompts me for the password.

But the way I want is that when I attempt to open the zip folder itself, it should prompt me for a password. How do I do that?

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/password-protect-folder-linux/ may provide the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @RishiC the zip format is really ill-chosen for this. 7-zip and rar will acheive this much easier.